# Mobile Push in Angular2

Tags: angular, push-notification

I want to use Mobile notifications in my `Angular` webapplication, is there someone who knows if this is possible?

Comment: You mean, when the user visit your website on its smartphone? Or is it an Ionic application?

Comment: It is an Angular2 webapplication, I want to send push notifications to the mobile @sakuto